# Opening a specific text document in a TextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Im currently developing a text editor program, and Ive run into a few problems. Im working on a spellchecker function for my program, and I want the users to be able to edit the dictionary file I use to check for correct spelling.

Im currently thinking a textArea is an easy way to show the text, but im having troubles showing the file to the users.

```
  void typeWords()
   {
   String ord = "";
   JTextArea listeOrd = new JTextArea(ord);
   JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listeOrd);
   listeOrd.setLineWrap(true);
   listeOrd.setWrapStyleWord(true);
   scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 600 ) );
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane,"Ordbok:", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
   }
```

this is the part of the code that controls this frame. Its not much, but my question is, is there a way to directly reference and print out the text file I want to? (example.txt) I would like it  to be editable, and saving it upon close, but I cant tackle those problems before I find a way to print the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at the [`JTextArea#read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object)) and [`JTextArea#write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer)) methods

As a general recommendations, I'd consider using a single column `JTable` instead, as it would allow you more easily edit the individual lines and control the format of the file

You may also want to take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)